# Given a UTI (Uniform Type Identifier), find all types to which it conforms

Tags: macos, uti, core-services, launch-services

I am writing an application that makes use of [Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html). Specifically, I am calling [`UTTypeCreateAllIdentifiersForTag()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UTTypeCreateAllIdentifiersForTag) and passing it various [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) types.

My hope was that this function (as distinct from `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag()`) would give me the most specific UTI as well as all the UTIs to which it conforms. This appears not to be the case -- it either returns a single UTI, or the secondary UTIs are spurious.

There is the `UTTypeConformsTo()` function defined in the same header file, but I'd prefer a function that returns an array of all the types to which this UTI conforms.

There appears to be hope for me, as [`MDItemCopyAttributeList()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MDItemCopyAttributeList) will return such a list. That said, it requires an `MDItemRef`, which can be created from either a file path or URL -- which isn't great. Sometimes my data is only stored in-memory and I only have a MIME type to go by.

Do I have to iterate through the entire database of UTIs to get this information or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was indeed missing something: the very obvious solution. While I was trawling through the symbols exported by `LaunchServices` (and noticed the interesting, but private `UTTypeCopyPedigree()`), I was reminded of `UTTypeCopyDeclaration()`, which *is* defined.

`UTTypeCopyDeclaration()` is given a UTI and returns (as a `CFDictionaryRef`) the property list in which the UTI was defined. The object in this dictionary with key `kUTTypeConformsToKey` is either a `CFArrayRef` or `CFStringRef`. In the case of an array, one can recursively iterate until a base type is reached.

This is how I built up an inheritance tree for a given UTI. I hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nst/UTIsExplorer generates a hierarchy graph of UTIs in "dot" format for graphviz.